# How to show critical points of function?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I have the following code:

```
ContourPlot3D[2x*z + 2y*z - y^3 - x^2 - 3z^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3,3}]
```

which correctly produces a 3D plot of the function specified.

I was wondering if there was a way to demonstrate the critical points of the function on this plot? There are two:

- (0,0,0) - saddle point
- (1/6,1/3,1/6) - local max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `Show`, to combine two graphics:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[
  2 x*z + 2 y*z - y^3 - x^2 - 3 z^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 
   3}],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0, 0, 0}], 
   Point[{1/6, 1/3, 1/6}]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Not possible in 3D with Epilog, as anything in the Epilog is taken to be 2D and rendered on top.

Comment: It is better to add `ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]` or another appropriate value to `ContourPlot3D` to show points behind the surface. And probably `Mesh -> None`, but I'm not sure what picture OP want.

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, I read the documentation after writing the answer :) It seems strange to me that there's nothing like Epilog3D.

Comment: I _think_ it might be because in 3D it doesn't make sense to have a layer _behind_ (Prolog) and a layer _in front of_ (Epilog) of the main graphics, like it does in 2D.  (Of course, even if it doesn't make _physical_ sense, it can certainly be rendered that way on a computer.)

Answer (score 2):

Related to the comments in [the first answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207161/):

**1.** Show with `ContourStyle`:

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[2 x*z + 2 y*z - y^3 - x^2 - 3 z^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0, 0, 0}], Point[{1/6, 1/3, 1/6}]}]]
```

**2.** Graphics objects merging:

```
gr = ContourPlot3D[2 x*z + 2 y*z - y^3 - x^2 - 3 z^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], gr[[1]], Opacity[1], {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0, 0, 0}], Point[{1/6, 1/3, 1/6}]}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]